# How to redefine model for Pytorch max pool error

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, nlp, pytorch

Hi I am trying to use tensor board for the model given at - https://github.com/siddharthvaria/WordPair-CNN/blob/master/src/pytorch_impl/cnn_pdtb_arg_multiclass_jl.py

However I get an error at Line 135
: x_max_pools = [F.max_pool1d(xi, xi.size(2)).squeeze(2) for xi in x_convs]

As

max_pool1d(): argument ‘kernel_size’ must be tuple of ints. Is there any solution to resolve this?

There is a discussion about this in pytorch forum - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/typeerror-avg-pool2d-argument-kernel-size-must-be-tuple-of-ints-not-proxy/108482

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line that raises error should be [line 135](https://github.com/siddharthvaria/WordPair-CNN/blob/master/src/pytorch_impl/cnn_pdtb_arg_multiclass_jl.py#L135):

```py
# At this point x_convs is [(batch_size, nfmaps_arg, seq_len_new), ...]*len(fsz_arg)
x_max_pools = [F.max_pool1d(xi, xi.size(2)).squeeze(2) for xi in x_convs]  # [(batch_size, nfmaps_arg), ...]*len(fsz_arg)
```

Actually `max_pool1d` reduces the size of the dimension n°2 that represents the sequence (after batch and channel dimension), [see the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool1d.html). Plus, according to the discuss you point out, the `kernel_size` argument now requires a concrete value at execution and cannot be inferred dynamically from inputs.

Fortunately your case is particularly simple because the kernel size is the entire sequence length. In other words, your pooling is actually a global max pooling that reduces the size of the sequence to only one scalar. This scalar is simply the maximum of all the values (check the shapes in comments!). So it is actually easy to implement a version without dynamic shapes. Just change line 135 by:

```py
x_max_pools = [torch.max(xi, dim=2, keepdim=True)[0] for xi in x_convs]  # [(batch_size, nfmaps_arg), ...]*len(fsz_arg)
```

Note:

- there is no direct implementation of `global_max_pooling` layer but as you can see it is just a `torch.max`
- Actually `torch.max` return a tuple `(max, max_indicies)` so you hae to take only the first element with `[0]` (see the [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html))
- gradients can propagate through `torch.max` like usual `max_pooling` layers (one source [see here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/confused-about-torch-max-and-gradient/14283) for instance)
- `torch.max(x, dim=2).squeeze(2)` is changed to `torch.max(x, dim=2, keepdim=True)` that is exactly the same thing but cleaner.

Comment: In the line just below (line number 137) :- x_max_pool = torch.cat(x_max_pools, 1) now returns an error - "TypeError: expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got torch.return_types.max".  I also see that now x_max_pools is now a list with each element in list now being of type <class 'torch.return_types.max'>

Comment: It is because `torch.max` actually returns a tuple `(max, max_indicies)` . You only need the first element. I edit my answer!